# Typescript: Object is possibly null event after an if in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a react application using Typescript and in my render method I have this error:

```
Object is possibly null
```

The thing is that I am already checking if the object is not null. Here is my code:

```
interface State {
  tutorial: any;
}

export default class Tutorial extends PureComponent<any, State> {
  state = {
    tutorial: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    loadTutorial(this.props.match.params.id).then((res: any) => {
      this.setState({ tutorial: res.tutorial });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.tutorial === null) return null;

    return (
      <section>
        <h1>Tutorial: {this.state.tutorial.title}</h1>;
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

But I still have the error in the render method. How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you use strict null checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd error. It seems to have to do with the fact that you don't have a type annotation where you initialize `state`, and you set `tutorial` to `null`:

```
state = {
  tutorial: null,
};
```

In other words, TypeScript thinks the type of `state` is literally `{ tutorial: null }` so you *can't* narrow away `null`. However I'd expect it to narrow to `never` which is why I find the error message odd.

Change that to this:

```
state: Readonly<State> = {
  tutorial: null,
};
```

And [your code works](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20class%20PureComponent%3CP%2C%20S%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20props%3A%20P%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20S%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setState%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20S%3E(state%3A%20Pick%3CS%2C%20K%3E)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20loadTutorial(id%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20tutorial%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Tutorial%20extends%20PureComponent%3Cany%2C%20State%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20Readonly%3CState%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tutorial%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20componentDidMount()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loadTutorial(this.props.match.params.id).then((res%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B%20tutorial%3A%20res.tutorial%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.state.tutorial%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3ETutorial%3A%20%24%7Bthis.state.tutorial.title%7D%3C%2Fh1%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fsection%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D). (Enable `strictNullChecks` to validate.)

Even though [React type definitions say `state: Readonly<S>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3a69de74e2a1e8025967f0077c0b3c551b83ac78/types/react/index.d.ts#L419) I've found that to get the correct behavior you often have to explicitly annotate the `state` property, else TypeScript will infer the type from the initialization value and that might not be the same as the `S` type arg passed to the component.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As a further insight, the issue is that without the annotation the state is inferred as `{ tutorial: null }`. This means `tutorial` will always be `null`, regardless of the check. The correct error would be "unreachable code", but I think the type error takes the precedence here.

Comment: you can reproduce the same error with `const x = { a: null }; if (x.a != null) { x.a.hey; }`

Comment: Thank you! Explicitly setting state to Readonly<State> or :State solves the issue